# Improving classifier performances in R for imbalanced dataset

Tags: machine-learning, r, xgboost, class-imbalance, ensemble-modeling

I have used an "adabag"(boosting + bagging) model on an imbalanced dataset (6% positive), I have tried to maximized the sensitivity while keeping the accuracy above 70% and the best results I got were:

- ROC= 0.711
- SENS=0.94
- SPEC=0.21

The results aren't Inhofe, especially the bad specificity.
Any suggestion on how to improve the result? Can the optimization be improved, or would the addition of a penalty term help?

This is the code:

```
ctrl <- trainControl(method = "cv",
                     number = 5,
                     repeats = 2, 
                     p = 0.80,
                     search = "grid", 
                     initialWindow = NULL, 
                     horizon = 1,
                     fixedWindow = TRUE,
                     skip = 0,
                     verboseIter = FALSE,
                     returnData = TRUE,
                     returnResamp = "final",
                     savePredictions = "all",
                     classProbs = TRUE,
                     summaryFunction = twoClassSummary,
                     preProcOptions = list(thresh = 0.80, ICAcomp = 3, k = 7, freqCut = 90/10,uniqueCut = 10, cutoff = 0.2),
                     sampling = "smote",
                     selectionFunction = "best",
                     index = NULL,
                     indexOut = NULL,
                     indexFinal = NULL,
                     timingSamps = 0,
                     predictionBounds = rep(FALSE, 2),
                     seeds = NA,
                     adaptive = list(min = 5,alpha = 0.05, method = "gls", complete = TRUE),
                     trim = FALSE,
                     allowParallel = TRUE)

grid <- expand.grid(maxdepth = 25, mfinal = 4000)

classifier <- train(x = training_set[,-1],y = training_set[,1], method = 'AdaBag',trControl = ctrl,metric = "ROC",tuneGrid = grid)
prediction <- predict(classifier, newdata= test_set,'prob')
```

plot from classifierplots package:

[image]

I tried xgboost as well.

Here is the code:

```
gbmGrid <- expand.grid(nrounds = 50, eta = 0.3,max_depth = 3,gamma = 0,colsample_bytree=0.6,min_child_weight=1,subsample=0.75)

ctrl <- trainControl(method = "cv",
                     number = 10,
                     repeats = 2, 
                     p = 0.80,
                     search = "grid", 
                     initialWindow = NULL, 
                     horizon = 1,
                     fixedWindow = TRUE,
                     skip = 0,
                     verboseIter = FALSE,
                     returnData = TRUE,
                     returnResamp = "final",
                     savePredictions = "all",
                     classProbs = TRUE,
                     summaryFunction = twoClassSummary,
                     sampling = "smote",
                     selectionFunction = "best",
                     index = NULL,
                     indexOut = NULL,
                     indexFinal = NULL,
                     timingSamps = 0,
                     predictionBounds = rep(FALSE, 2),
                     seeds = NA,
                     adaptive = list(min = 5,alpha = 0.05, method = "gls", complete = TRUE),
                     trim = FALSE,
                     allowParallel = TRUE)

classifier <- train(x = training_set[,-1],y = training_set[,1], method = 'xgbTree',metric = "ROC",trControl = ctrl,tuneGrid = gbmGrid)
prediction <- predict(classifier, newdata= test_set[,-1],'prob')
```

plot from classifierplots package:

[image]

**Update:**

I tried asymmetric adaboost, this is the code:

```
model_weights <- ifelse(training_set$readmmited == "yes",
                        (1/table(training_set$readmmited)[1]) * 0.4,
                        (1/table(training_set$readmmited)[2]) * 0.6)


ctrl <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv",
                     number = 5,
                     repeats = 2, 
                     search = "grid", 
                     returnData = TRUE,
                     returnResamp = "final",
                     savePredictions = "all",
                     classProbs = TRUE,
                     summaryFunction = twoClassSummary,
                     selectionFunction = "best",
                     allowParallel = TRUE)

classifier <- train(x = training_set[,-1],y = training_set[,1], method = 'ada',trControl = ctrl,metric = "ROC",weights = model_weights)
```

but the specificity is zero, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think asymmetric Adaboost should do the trick. Please try that once and see the scores.

Comment: @Rahul do you know how to interrupt the plots from classifierplots?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that can you elaborate?

Comment: @Rahul why asymmetric Adaboost? do you see something in the classifierplots to suggest that?

Comment: The fact that you were using XG boost gave me the idea. Also, you've mentioned that it was an imbalanced dataset. Asymmetric Adaboost works particularly well with Imbalanced datasets which aren't artificially supersampled. It is able to have higher accuracy because you have to give a certain weight to a sample. This helps overcome the imbalanced dataset disadvantage.

Comment: @Rahul so if I have been using xgboost + oversample I can replace it with asymmetric Adaboost without even over sampling? where can I find that model? I don't think it's available in caret package.

Comment: Yes, that's right. If I'm not wrong there is no such package as Asymmetric Adaboost in any toolkit. Asymmetric Adabost refers to adding weights to each of your sample. This ensures gives a better accuracy despite having an imbalanced dataset.

Comment: @Rahul isn't regular Adabost gives weights to each sample already? if not, how do I do this in the caret package?

Comment: No, it doesn't and about caret I'm not entirely sure. I'm more of a python user myself.

Comment: @Rahul Aedula I tried  Asymmetric Adaboost  with no oversampling but i got worse result.. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do this. Keep constant weights for one class and vary the value of weights for the other class by small increments of 0.05 until you get a good classification score. When you do that is your weights and  corresponding score.

Comment: @Rahul Aedula can you explain further how do I code this?

Comment: Start with a weight for a class, Class 1 let's Say. And the other class, Class 2 ,the same weight. Classify and check the score. Now increment the weight of the second class by some small number. Such as 0.05 or so and check if the classifier increases accuracy and keep iterating. If the classifiers accuracy increases as this continues. Repeat this step until you get the step until you get the maximum possible accuracy. If the accuracy declines then switch up the weights between the two classes. Keep class 2 constant and increment the weights and check for this class 1. And run the same drill.

Comment: @Rahul Aedula I have tried that in adaboost but with or witout the weight I get sort of the same result which is almost 100% sensitivity and 0% specificity... I have no idea why (didn't use smote!!)

Comment: what happens when you use smote? It should supersample

Comment: @Rahul Aedula without using smote or any undersample I get 100% sensitivity and 0% specificity..how it can be possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should try compensating for the imbalanced data and then can you try a lot of different classifiers. Either balance it out, use SMOTE to interpolate (this always struck me as too magical), or assign weights.

Here's a nice article walking through it with caret, which is what it appears you're using:

http://dpmartin42.github.io/blogposts/r/imbalanced-classes-part-1

Comment: that's great. thank you. i will try and report back.

Comment: @Rahul Aedula I tried  Asymmetric Adaboost  with no oversampling but i got worse result.. what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

SMOTE is a good strategy and also I have got significant accuracy, ROC with cost-sensitive classification. In life science, we handle a lot of imbalance datasets this paper describes approach how to handle it. https://jcheminf.springeropen.com/articles/10.1186/1758-2946-1-21